# Convert unsinged char array from objective-c to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> swift

Tags: objective-c, c, swift

I have an `unsigned char` array in .h file. and, also I have a function that takes unsigned char array as input. When I try to call this function in swift, it gets `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`. So, automatic objective-c to swift converter thinks `unsigned char` should be converted as `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`. But, I can not pass my variable to this function directly. Because I get,

```
Cannot convert value of type '(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>!'
```

Length of this array is static. So, I can create

```
let key = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 64);
```

and, also I can get value by `KEY.0`, `KEY.1` ... etc. So, all I need is to create a for loop to read value from `KEY` and assign it to `key`

```
 for index in 1...64 {
     key[index] = KEY[index];
 }
```

but, this gives compilation error as:

```
 Value of tuple type '(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)' has no member 'index'
```

so, first question, how I can get any value from `KEY` by index. Second is, is there any easier way to convert a `unsigned char` array to `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C array

```
unsigned char ckey[64];
```

is imported as a tuple in Swift:

```
public var ckey: (UInt8, ..., UInt8)
```

and one cannot access the tuple elements by subscripting with an index.
(Well, you *can* when using `Mirror`).

However:

- The address of a C array is the same as the address of the first
  array element, and
- for structures *imported from C,* Swift preserves the memory layout.

The latter was [confirmed by Apple engineer Joe Groff:](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160516/001980.html)

> ... You can leave the struct defined in C and import it into Swift. Swift will respect C's layout.

Therefore you can pass the address of the first tuple element to 
the function:

```
f(key: &ckey.0)
```

Of course – as in C – the information about the size of the array is
lost, so the array should be NUL-terminated, or `f` should *know*
about the array size. Alternatively, pass the size
as an additional argument to the function:

```
foo(key: &ckey.0, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: ckey))
```